# mouseover not working for D3 multi-line chart lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a multi-line chart using D3 of nested data, my original data is a JSON with attributes including country, rank and year, including data from years 2015 to 2018.  I nested the data by country. I was able to successfully draw the lines, but when I want to add a mouseover event for each line (for example I would like the opacity of all other lines to decrease when hovering over one line) it doesn't seem to work.  When I add mouseover events for the labels or axes it works, but not for the lines. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Original data:

```
var data =
[
  {
    "country": "Democratic Republic of the Congo",
    "count": 475694,
    "rank": 1,
    "year": 2015
  },
  {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "count": 419815,
    "rank": 2,
    "year": 2015
  },
  {
    "country": "Angola",
    "count": 343960,
    "rank": 3,
    "year": 2015
  }, ...];
```

Code

```
var dataByCountry = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.country;
    })
    .entries(data);

var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
    },
    width = ($(".chart").width() - 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

var minWidth = 450,
    maxWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1200 ? 1000 : 800,
    scrollBarPadding = 10,
    outerWidth = Math.max(minWidth, Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth - scrollBarPadding, maxWidth));

var widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([450, 1000])
    .range([60, 150]);

var margin = {
    top: Math.round(widthScale(outerWidth)) * 0.8,
    right: Math.round(widthScale(outerWidth)),
    bottom: Math.round(widthScale(outerWidth)) * 0.8,
    left: Math.round(widthScale(outerWidth))
};
var width = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 6.5 * width;

var countries2018 = ["Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Australia", "Angola", "Russia", "Sudan", "Brazil", "Zambia", "Central African Republic", "Mozambique", "United States", "India", "China", "United Republic of Tanzania", "Nigeria", "Guinea", "Venezuela", "Canada", "Madagascar", "Mexico", "Argentina", "Ethiopia", "Chad", "Bolivia", "Ghana", "South Africa", "Cameroon", "Burma", "Iraq", "Indonesia", "Colombia", "Kazakhstan", "Paraguay", "Cambodia", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Mali", "Zimbabwe", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Congo", "Sierra Leone", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "Thailand", "Senegal", "Peru", "Pakistan", "Viet Nam", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Namibia", "Togo", "Honduras", "Malawi", "Turkey", "Papua New Guinea", "Chile", "Algeria", "Guatemala", "Liberia", "Ecuador", "Nicaragua", "Philippines", "Guinea-Bissau", "Serbia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Cuba", "Italy", "Romania", "Malaysia", "Germany", "Nepal", "Turkmenistan", "Japan", "Uzbekistan", "Saudi Arabia", "Bangladesh", "Bulgaria", "Gabon", "Spain", "Kenya", "France", "Guyana", "El Salvador", "Dominican Republic", "Egypt", "Portugal", "Oman", "Belarus", "Azerbaijan", "Niger", "Swaziland", "Costa Rica", "Panama", "Sweden", "Korea, Republic of", "Sri Lanka", "Gambia", "Uruguay", "United Kingdom", "Greece", "Belize", "Vanuatu", "Timor-Leste", "Belgium", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Mongolia", "Poland", "Reunion", "Kuwait", "Suriname", "The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Republic of Moldova", "Armenia", "Kyrgyzstan", "Fiji", "New Zealand", "Georgia", "Austria", "Qatar", "Taiwan", "Burundi", "Slovakia", "Netherlands", "Hungary", "Haiti", "Finland", "Morocco", "French Guiana", "Croatia", "New Caledonia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Eritrea", "Czech Republic", "Albania", "Jamaica", "Lesotho", "Somalia", "Equatorial Guinea", "Bhutan", "United Arab Emirates", "Latvia", "Bahamas", "Norway", "Mauritania", "Afghanistan", "Ireland", "Yemen", "Montenegro", "Rwanda", "Israel", "Tunisia", "Luxembourg", "Switzerland", "Denmark", "Lithuania", "Tajikistan", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Estonia", "Puerto Rico", "Jordan", "Comoros", "Lebanon", "Cyprus", "Mauritius", "Samoa", "Barbados", "Palestine", "Djibouti", "Bahrain", "French Polynesia", "Solomon Islands", "Brunei Darussalam", "Cape Verde", "Maldives", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Hong Kong", "Slovenia", "Guam", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Greenland", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Antigua and Barbuda", "British Virgin Islands", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Western Sahara", "Guadeloupe", "Martinique", "Singapore", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Aruba", "French Southern and Antarctic Lands", "Malta", "Tonga", "United States Virgin Islands", "Grenada", "Iceland"];


var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#B5C660", "#B3C762", "#B0C765", "#ADC767", "#AAC769", "#A7C76A", "#A3C66B", "#9FC46B", "#9AC26A",
        "#94BF68", "#8EBB66", "#87B662", "#7FB05E", "#75AA5A", "#6BA354", "#609B4F", "#549249", "#478943", "#39803D",
        "#2C7739", "#206F36", "#166A35", "#0F6638", "#0B663E", "#0C6A48", "#127257", "#1B7D6A", "#27897F", "#359795",
        "#42A4AB", "#4EB0C0", "#58BAD3", "#5DBFE2", "#5DC0EC", "#5ABCF2", "#52B5F4", "#49ABF3", "#3E9FEE", "#3292E7",
        "#2785DE", "#1E77D3", "#176AC7", "#125EBA", "#0F53AB", "#0E489C", "#0D3E8D", "#0E347D", "#0F2B6C", "#11215C"
    ])
    .domain(countries2018);


var startYear = 2015, //2010
    endYear = 2018, //2019
    yearRange = endYear - startYear;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([startYear, endYear]).range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 200]).range([0, height]),
    y2 = d3.scaleBand().domain(countries2018).range([0, height + 10])


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(4).tickFormat(d3.format("d")).tickSize(0),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(200).tickSize(0),
    yAxis2 = d3.axisRight(y2).ticks(200).tickSize(0);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.year);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.rank);
    })


var chart = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "chartWrapper")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");




//Append x axis to chart
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .style("font-size", 13)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 9) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

//Append y axis to chart
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "titles")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("x", -(height / 2))
    .attr("y", -35)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("font-size", 14)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Position in Top 10");

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis2")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 2) + ",-10)")
    .call(yAxis2);

d3.select(".axis2 path").attr("stroke", "none");


var chartG = chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chart");

var chartWrapper = chartG.selectAll(".line")
    .data(dataByCountry, function(d) {
        return d.key;
    });


chartWrapper.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log(d)
    }) //doesn't work
    .style("stroke-width", 4)
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.key);
    })
    .attr("fill", "none");


d3.selectAll(".axis2 text").on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
}) //works

d3.selectAll(".chart path").on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
}) //doesn't work
```

And here is a link to my fiddle (I added the json data directly to the JS so the relevant code starts from line 4805): https://jsfiddle.net/jhjanicki/rjyxu463/12/

Comment: With NVD3.js such charts are easy to plot.

Comment: yes, but I plan on doing a lot more customization with the visualization instead of just having a line chart, this is just the first step.

Comment: This does not limit that; it's just a D3 charting library.

Comment: @MartinZeitler OP is correct, it limits a lot: NVD3 is just a charting tool, the user is restricted to their visual encodings. D3, on the other hand, is a low level library of methods, one can do almost anything (related to data visualisation) with D3.

Comment: @jhjanicki You have `.style("pointer-events", "none")`, no wonder your mouse events are not being fired! Just remove that. I'm voting to close this question as *"typo"*, which encompasses cases like this.

Comment: Oh ya, I didn't realize I left that line in. Thank you!